# Oracle SQL Nested Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Table Z has A-M columns:
I have to display columns A,C,F,G,K,L,M with following conditions:
a. Search for selected date range(column A is date column)
b. Display top 10 rows where K> 5000
c. If the above returns less than 10 rows then find remaining rows where L> 500
d. If both above results return less than total of 10 rows then find remaining rows where M>50

PS: Rows will be total of 10 made out of result from b,c and d

Comment: Because you didn't read the faq.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an analytic function

```
SELECT <<whatever you want>>
  FROM (SELECT z.*,
               row_number() over (order by case when k > 5000 then 1 else 2 end,
                                           case when l > 500 then 1 else 2 end,
                                           case when m > 50 then 1 else 2 end) rn
          FROM z
         WHERE a BETWEEN <<lower date>> and <<upper date>>)
 WHERE rn <= 10
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what 1 and 2 inside case statement means?

Comment: @root.  They're just numbers.  1 sorts before 2.  You could use 17 and 99 or 'A' and 'B' or any other constants that sort the way you want them to.